# Formatting WebGrid with Bootstrap not display colors as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webgrid

I'm using the MVC WebGrid and I'm trying to format it using Bootstrap styling. However, the Edit button I'm using is not formatted like I would expect. I'm using the Cerulean theme off of Bootswath. I'm setting the button to the "warning" style and I'm getting the orange background along with the rounded edges for the button but the text inside the button is blue instead of white like I would expect. Am I using Bootstrap with the grid in the wrong way?

Here is my Grid. The header style I just set to the Cerulean's "Info".

```
@grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-striped table-hover",
headerStyle: "info",

mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
firstText: "<< First",
previousText: "< Prev",
nextText: "Next >",
lastText: "Last >>",

columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column(columnName: "CallDate", header: "Call Day", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:ddd}", item.CallDate)),
    grid.Column(columnName: "CallDate", header: "Call Date", format: (item) => string.Format("{0:d}", item.CallDate)),
    grid.Column(columnName: "CustomerName", header: "Customer Name"),
    grid.Column(columnName: "Subject", header: "Subject"),
    grid.Column(columnName: "PhoneNumber", header: "Phone Number"),
    grid.Column(columnName: "CallTypeName", header: "Call Type"),
    grid.Column(columnName: "StatusName", header: "Status"),
    grid.Column(header: "Edit", format: (item) =>
    {
        var link = Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id });
        return link;
    }, style: "btn btn-warning btn-md")
    ))
```

Here is my Site.css.

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}

/* Offsets for vertical spacing */
.voffset  { margin-top: 2px; }
.voffset1 { margin-top: 5px; }
.voffset2 { margin-top: 10px; }
.voffset3 { margin-top: 15px; }
.voffset4 { margin-top: 30px; }
.voffset5 { margin-top: 40px; }
.voffset6 { margin-top: 60px; }
.voffset7 { margin-top: 80px; }
.voffset8 { margin-top: 100px; }
.voffset9 { margin-top: 150px; }
```

Comment: Is it possible there's some other CSS affecting text in anchor tags?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm not great with the debug tools but when I use F12 in Chrome and click on the element it looks as though it's applying Bootstrap to it. Wish I could post a screen shot but there are a bunch of styles that are crossed out. However I did find the style called .btn-warning and it has the color: #ffffff and the background-color: #dd5600. That is the white and orange as I would expect. I can't find anything that shows a color: set to some kind of blue color. On the main element section to the left it has class="btn btn-warning btn-md".

Comment: I found another thing that looks odd. Even thought I have the tablestyle for the WebGrid set to "table table-bordered" the border is missing around on the Edit column. It's almost like the CSS is getting applied differently because the the HTML.ActionLink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a fix. I was thinking it might have something to do with the ActionLink I was using (which I had found in an example). Here is what I found that ended up working. Edit is the ActionResult for my controller calle "Grid".

```
grid.Column(header: "Action", format:@<text> <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Grid", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Edit</a></text>)
```

Hopefully this helps someone else.